# Why does Chrome not work as expected?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I built dynamic notes bar to implant in one of my educational games. The scenario is triggered when the user clicks on one of the options of a select element. 
It works as expected on Firefox (57) and on Explorer (11), but when tests with Chrome (63) it fails to update/show the note. 
The console log is empty.
Basically the function adds and removes CSS class with timeout, which is set with animation property. 
I try to make it as accessible as can be, so any extra notes would be wonderful!

Here is my stripped code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #dynamicNote { visibility: hidden; opacity: 1;}
      .show { visibility: visible!important; -webkit-animation: fadein  0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 2s; animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 2s; }
      @-webkit-keyframes fadein { 
        from { opacity: 0; } 
        to { opacity: 1; }
      }
      @keyframes fadein {
        from { opacity: 0; }  
        to { opacity: 1; }
      }
      @-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
        from { opacity: 1; } 
        to { opacity: 0; }
      }
      @keyframes fadeout {
        from { opacity: 1; } 
        to { opacity: 0; }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="dynamicNote">dynamic notes bar</p>
    <form>
      <label for="gameLang">Choose Language</label>
      <select name="gameLang" id="gameLang">
        <option value="he" selected="true">Hebrew</option>
        <option value="en" onclick="showNote(note='Note1');">English</option>
        <option value="ar" onclick="showNote(note='Note2');">Arab</option>
        <option value="ru" onclick="showNote(note='Note3');">Rus</option>
      </form>
      <script>
        function showNote(note) { 
        var noteBar = document.getElementById('dynamicNote');
        noteBar.textContent = note.toString();
        noteBar.className = 'show';
        setTimeout(function(){ noteBar.className = noteBar.className.replace('show', ''); }, 3000);
        }
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how **select** works, you have no **closing tag** and where's your **onchange** event handler? Study the corrections below...

```
<select onchange="showNote(this.value);" name="gameLang" id="gameLang">
 <option value="he" selected>Hebrew</option>
 <option value="en">English</option>
 <option value="ar">Arab</option>
 <option value="ru">Rus</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. 1. Omitting the end of option tag is optional as far as I understand. 2. As @yuriy636 commented – chrome doesn't support onclick events with option element so (and like you kindly suggested) the proper way is to use the onchange event with the select element.

Comment: No, no, no... nothing to do with rendering engines. That's how the select works in ALL modern browsers, and closing tags are NOT optional. Only 16 "singletons" don't have one and select is not one of them.

Comment: Tag omission: The start tag is mandatory. The end tag is optional if this element is immediately followed by another <option> element or an <optgroup>, or if the parent element has no more content. - taken from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option